# Postgresql select max performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have very simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myscheme.get_last_timecode(ptable_ids integer[], ptimecode bigint DEFAULT NULL::bigint)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
  SELECT MAX(timecode) AS timecode
  FROM myscheme.event
  WHERE table_id = ANY($1) AND ($2 IS NULL OR timecode <= $2);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE
  COST 100;
```

Count of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myscheme.event WHERE table_id = 1; -- 120
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myscheme.event WHERE table_id = 2; -- 18
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myscheme.event WHERE table_id = 3; -- 839795
```

The results are quite unexpected:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT myscheme.get_last_timecode(ARRAY[1], NULL) -- Total runtime: 212.552 ms
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT myscheme.get_last_timecode(ARRAY[2], NULL) -- Total runtime: 213.713 ms
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT myscheme.get_last_timecode(ARRAY[3], NULL) -- Total runtime: 0.186 ms (the fastest!)
```

When I use plain query, execution time is normal:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT MAX(timecode) AS timecode FROM myscheme.event
  WHERE table_id = ANY(ARRAY[1]) AND (NULL IS NULL OR timecode <= NULL);

Aggregate  (cost=10.18..10.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.079..0.079 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using event_table_id_index on event  (cost=0.42..10.05 rows=51 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.067 rows=120 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (table_id = ANY ('{1}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 0.101 ms
```

but it uses another execution plan for table_id = 3:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT MAX(timecode) AS timecode FROM poker.event
  WHERE table_id = ANY(ARRAY[3]) AND (NULL IS NULL OR timecode <= NULL);

Result  (cost=0.47..0.48 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Index Scan Backward using event_timecode_key on event  (cost=0.42..35873.11 rows=845301 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (timecode IS NOT NULL)
                Filter: (table_id = ANY ('{3}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 0.038 ms
```

Can anybody explain me how to create a function (or index) whose execution time will not depend on the amount of data?

```
SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 9.3.14 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit
```

And the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE myscheme.event
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  table_id integer,
  deal_id bigint,
  type_id integer NOT NULL,
  timecode bigserial NOT NULL,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  parent_id bigint,
  prev_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT event_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT event_deal_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (deal_id)
      REFERENCES myscheme.deal (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT event_parent_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES myscheme.event (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT event_prev_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (prev_id)
      REFERENCES myscheme.event (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT event_table_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (table_id)
      REFERENCES myscheme.tables (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT event_type_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
      REFERENCES myscheme.event_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT event_timecode_key UNIQUE (timecode)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX event_deal_id_index ON myscheme.event USING btree (deal_id);
CREATE INDEX event_table_id_index ON myscheme.event  USING btree (table_id);
CREATE INDEX event_type_id_index ON myscheme.event USING btree (type_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the statistics the execution plans make perfect sense. 
The table has around 840k tuples almost all of table id 3. 
So if you're looking for `max(timecode)` scanning the timecode index backwards makes perfect sense with table id 3 (almost every line you hit has that id).

But if you're looking for table id 1 - you have only 120 tuples out of 840k, your best bet is to scan these 120 tuples looking for the  `max(timecode)`.

It's like looking for a needle in a hay stack - looking for hay is simpler than looking for the needle.

Hope it made some sense into what the optimizer planned.

Btw, you could try to build a composite index of table id and timecode - I'm not near a db to check but I think PG could use that to skip to the max timecode per table id directly. 
- worth a shot :)

Regards 
Jony